# using eclipse to connect to remote machine[linux server] using ssh

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, plugins, ssh

I am searching out for solution to use any of the IDE's such as Netbeans/ eclipse to run .jsp and .java files from a remote machine using linux as the OS. The .java and .jsp files are on the server . So, an IDE which would let me access the server and let me update the files directly on the server would be great. I use SSH terminal to connect to the server to update and get files. Now, if there was an easier way to just have an access using IDE to the linux remote machine. that would be great. Please let me know regarding the same. Thank you very much for your time.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solutions would be either to NFSmount the directory on the remote machine to your local machine. Or install something like dropbox that will sync the machines.

Is your local machine windows or linux? If it's windows, you can use WinSCP to keep the remote directory in sync with the local one. It will auto scp files when they change to the remote server.

If it's linux, I wrote a command line python script that does the same

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scpy/

Comment: Thanks, but my question is that I am trying to use an IDE which will enable me to access the linux server which stores all the .java and .jsp files. The server uses SSH to connect. So, how do I go about connecting my IDE (either Eclipse/ netbeans) to a remote machine?

Comment: I do use sSH terminal just like WinSCP, but how do I integrate the directory structure with the netbeans/Eclipse.Arent there plugin's or tools which can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the Eclipse Remote System Explorer.  See [Ikool's Blog](http://ikool.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/ssh-access-through-eclipse-rse/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

like falmarri said, it's best if u can sync your files on the remote machine to your local machine. you can sync them by either using his script, or manually scp'ing or ftp'ing your files.

but my personal preference is to use mercurial or svn or other repositories. in addition to being able to sync my files, i also have access to some amazing version control of my code.

Comment: Okay. And how do I resolve the problem of importing the .java files on the server and compiling them on jsp..?